# How do I stop my assets from scaling twice in UWP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I used to have only 100% scale assets without the .scale-100 part of the extension and everything looked fine (albeit low res) on differently scaled screens. Now that I've added .scale-100, .scale-125, .scale-150, .scale-200, and .scale-400 assets, things no longer scale properly. It looks as if I'm getting the correct image file, but then something is scaling it as if it were the 100% image, so the image grows relative to its container as the scale increases. Is there some option I have to turn off to stop this from happening? I'm using xamarin forms. Example screenshots below, image sizes for the plus and hamburger icons are 32x32, 40x40, 48x48, 64x64, and 128x128 respectively.

The images are created using this code

```
        _image = new Image
        {
            Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            Source = $"Assets/menu.png"
        };
```

and added to a horizontal stack layout

Screen set to 100% (normal padding, how it's supposed to look.)

[image: 100%]

125%

[image]

150%

[image]

200%

[image]

300%

[image]

Comment: Could you please post your XAML as well?

Comment: @MartinZikmund we don't use xaml, but I've added the image constructor

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue. Could you provide more detail about page layout ?